# How to assign default values to map(object()) input in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

When defining a complex input variable:

```
variable "s3_shares" {
  type = map(object({
    s3_bucket_arn         = string
    client_list           = list(string)
    read_only             = bool
    default_storage_class = string
  }))
}
```

How can one deal with `read_only` and `default_storage_class` being mutually exclusive? In other words, when using the module and defining an `s3_share` with `read_only = true` the `default_storage_class` could be omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [validation{}](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#custom-validation-rules) block and [alltrue()](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/alltrue) function :

```hcl
variable "s3_shares" {
  type = map(object({
    s3_bucket_arn         = string
    client_list           = list(string)
    read_only             = bool
    default_storage_class = string
  }))
default = {
  "one" = {
    s3_bucket_arn         = "foo"
    client_list           = ["foo","bar"]
    read_only             = false
    default_storage_class = "bar" # IS OK
}
  "two" = {
    s3_bucket_arn         = "foo"
    client_list           = ["foo","bar"]
    read_only             = false
    default_storage_class = "" # IS OK
}}
  "three" = {
    s3_bucket_arn         = "foo"
    client_list           = ["foo","bar"]
    read_only             = true
    default_storage_class = "" # IS OK
}}
  "four" = {
    s3_bucket_arn         = "foo"
    client_list           = ["foo","bar"]
    read_only             = true
    default_storage_class = "bar" # IS KO
}}

validation {
  condition = alltrue([
     for o in var.s3_shares : !(o.read_only && length(o.default_storage_class) > 0)])
     error_message = "Read_only and default_storage_class are exclusive."     
   }
}
```

Mind the use case **"two"** where `read_only` is set to `false` and `default_storage_class` is empty : this will return `true`. This might not be the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of the validation block before.
Could this though also be used with the `map` wrapped around the object?

Comment: No worries. I think that would still works, but I struggle to understand why you need a `map` there.  Would you mind explaining me the usecase ?

Comment: Of course, I don't mind, :) I'm deploying the AWS Storage Gateway and one gateway will have multiple file shares. The `object` describes the individual share, and the `map` brings all shares together that belong to the gateway.
I will give the solution a try and mark it working later :)

Comment: I've updated my answer. It works like a charm on my side ;)